# What is the type for content of button to store xaml data in resource?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794412/how-to-use-xaml-vector-images-as-image-source-in-window-8-app/14822454#14822454), I want to use a same solution to do with button. But I want to store the content to an other resource.(I mean XamlImage in below sample) What is the type for content of button to store xaml data in resource dictionary?

Below is sample from the post. I added XamlImage as path in resource but it doesn't work. So, what type should it be?

```
<Path x:Key="XamlImage" Data="M383.518,230.427C299.063,230.427 230.355,299.099 230.355,383.554 230.355,468.009 299.063,536.644 383.518,536.644 467.937,536.644 536.645,468.009 536.645,383.554 536.645,299.099 467.937,230.427 383.518,230.427z M340.229,0L426.771,0C436.838,0,445.035,8.19732,445.035,18.2643L445.035,115.303C475.165,122.17,503.532,133.928,529.634,150.43L598.306,81.6869C601.721,78.3074 606.359,76.3653 611.213,76.3653 616.031,76.3653 620.704,78.3074 624.12,81.6869L685.278,142.916C692.397,150.035,692.397,161.648,685.278,168.767L616.677,237.402C633.108,263.54,644.866,291.907,651.733,322.001L748.736,322.001C758.803,322.001,767,330.198,767,340.265L767,426.806C767,436.873,758.803,445.07,748.736,445.07L651.769,445.07C644.901,475.235,633.108,503.531,616.677,529.669L685.278,598.305C688.694,601.72 690.635,606.358 690.635,611.212 690.635,616.102 688.694,620.705 685.278,624.12L624.085,685.313C620.525,688.872 615.851,690.67 611.177,690.67 606.503,690.67 601.865,688.872 598.269,685.313L529.67,616.678C503.567,633.109,475.2,644.937,445.035,651.804L445.035,748.771C445.035,758.838,436.838,767,426.771,767L340.229,767C330.162,767,321.965,758.838,321.965,748.771L321.965,651.804C291.8,644.937,263.433,633.109,237.366,616.678L168.731,685.313C165.315,688.693 160.677,690.67 155.823,690.67 151.005,690.67 146.296,688.693 142.916,685.313L81.7221,624.12C74.6033,617.036,74.6033,605.424,81.7221,598.305L150.323,529.669C133.892,503.603,122.099,475.235,115.267,445.07L18.2643,445.07C8.19734,445.07,0,436.873,0,426.806L0,340.265C0,330.198,8.19734,322.001,18.2643,322.001L115.267,322.001C122.135,291.907,133.892,263.54,150.323,237.402L81.7221,168.767C78.3064,165.351 76.3655,160.713 76.3655,155.859 76.3655,150.97 78.3064,146.332 81.7221,142.916L142.916,81.7582C146.476,78.1988 151.149,76.4016 155.823,76.4016 160.497,76.4016 165.171,78.1988 168.731,81.7582L237.366,150.43C263.469,133.928,291.837,122.17,321.965,115.303L321.965,18.2643C321.965,8.19732,330.162,0,340.229,0z"/>

<Style x:Key="PathAppBarButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" TargetType="ButtonBase">
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Width="20" Height="20" 
                Stretch="Uniform" 
                Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
                Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>

<Style x:Key="CrossButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource PathAppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="CrossAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Cross"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource XamlImage}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to set an image resource as your content because `Image` is a control and it can only be in one place in your UI tree. You can reuse a `DataTemplate` though in your `ContentTemplate`. So just put an `Image` inside of that.

Comment: As I understand what you said, I didn't want to use an image. I want to use xaml data. (maybe I misunderstand what you want to say) However, I added a Path as I added in project in the sample.

Comment: `Path` is an element which you can't reuse. Just put the XamlImage `Path` in the template in your `PathAppBarButtonStyle`. Templates are used to generate new copies of elements inside, so you can reuse them in your app as opposed to element resources.